# How to terminate server process?

Tags: bash, email, scripts, automation

I just created automation sending an email using a shell script, but it always running and send me an email every sec to my email.

I'm using PID and that process name to terminate it, I'm writing several ways such as

```
  kill -9 myscrip.sh
```

or

```
  pkill -9/-15 myscrip.sh
```

etc and its always shown up `no process killed`. on the other hand, that PID of my script its always changed everytime I'm using

```
  ps aux | grep myscrip.sh
```

Is there any way I can kill the process with the VSZ ?

Comment: ...you created a fork bomb... try `killall -KILL myscript.sh`